# Time out after waiting for visibility of element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble with consistently selecting the flight return date from a travel search site. Sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't and I'm pretty stumped at this point. The error I'm receiving is: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ui-datepicker-div`

I've set up a few Wait statements for the date elements I'm clicking against, but I'm still receiving an error. I'm trying to find a solution where I can avoid using Thread.sleep. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my script:

```
public class DatePickerTest {
    private static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        driver.get("http://lowfares.com");
        selectDepartDate(2016, 5, 18);
        selectReturnDate(2016, 5, 21);
    }

    public static void selectDepartDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        month--; // replacing zero based index
        Integer.toString(year);
        Integer.toString(month);
        Integer.toString(day);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("depart_date")));

        // click on text box to open up date picker calendar
        driver.findElement(By.id("depart_date")).click();

        // close pop up window
        String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();
        String subWindowHandler = null;
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);

        // wait for calendar interface to appear
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ui-datepicker-div")));

        // select depart date
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@data-month, " + month + ") and contains(@data-year, " + year + ")]//a[contains(text(), " + day + ")]")).click();
    }

    public static void selectReturnDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        month--; // replacing zero based index
        Integer.toString(year);
        Integer.toString(month);
        Integer.toString(day);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("return_date")));

        // click on text box to open up date picker calendar
        driver.findElement(By.id("return_date")).click();

        // wait for calendar interface to appear
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ui-datepicker-div")));

        // select return date
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@data-month, " + month + ") and contains(@data-year, " + year + ")]//a[contains(text(), " + day + ")]")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1. `depart_date` is a div, you shouldn't be clicking on it, instead click on `<input id="depart"`:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("depart")).click();
   ```
2. Not sure what popup window is doing (I didn't get any popup). In any case, check first that popup window was really there:

   ```
   ...
   Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
   for (String windowHandle : handles) {
        subWindowHandler = windowHandle;
   }
   if(subWindowHandler != null && !subWindowHandler.equals(parentWindowHandler) {
       driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
       driver.close();
       driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
   }
   ...
   ```
3. If you did close popup, and switched back to the main window, you need to make sure calendar is still open; if not, reopen it:

   ```
   public void isCalendarVisible() {
       try {
           WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ui-datepicker-div")));
           return true;
       } catch (TimeOutException e) {
           return false;
   }
   ```

   and then under

   ```
   // wait for calendar interface to appear
   if(!isCalendarVisible()) {
       // try to reopen calendar
       driver.findElement(By.id("depart")).click();
   }
   ```
4. Neat-picking: the following doesn't do anything:

   ```
   Integer.toString(year);
   Integer.toString(month);
   Integer.toString(day);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to keep in mind with Visibility of an element.

Visible is different than the element being present.  This can get you in trouble if you look for the wrong sub-element or part of the object that is not actually visible.  You may want to try `presenceOfElementLocated(by)` or try a different element that maybe a visible part.

Sometimes (quite often) elements on the same page have the same identifiers.  If you use `findElement` (and most things do) it only gets the first one it finds.  If that one is hidden you can wait all day and it will never be visible.  Try using `By.cssSelector` to help choose objects more specifically. Example:

```
[class*='exampleContainer'] [id='ui-datepicker-div']
```

You could also create a `findDisplayedElement()` function.  This could `findElements()` and iterate through them until it finds one that `element.isDisplayed() = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed through my journey with Selenium, that sometimes my Explicit waits, have issues with `xpath` elements, while the `driver.findElement` has no issues finding it.  I have also noticed that even though I try to stay away from using `By.cssSelector`, that `By.cssSelector` always seems to fix those pesky time outs from my explicit.  So I agree with Chuck.  If your timing out from a `xpath` element within your Explicit Wait, then try using a `By.cssSelector`.  You may be surprised.